# how to add the SECRET path so that i can get the client email in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
secrets_base_path = os.environ['SECRETS_PATH']
SECRET = open(secrets_base_path+"/bbak_crewl.yaml", "r")

with open(SECRET) as jf:
    json_secrets = json_load(jf)

json_secrets['client_email']

gs = pygsheets.authorize(service_ file=SECRET)
```

receiving an error when trying to run this python file, i know the code needs to be corrected , pls help.

expected str,bytes or os.Path like object, not to _io.Text10wrapper error

Comment: please remove the picture of text ... add the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert the TextIO to string and you should use "loads" function;

```
from json import loads

with open(SECRET) as jf:
    data = loads(jf.read())
```